# CSS Input date width inside table

Tags: html, css, percentage, html-input

I am having some issues working with `<input type='date'>` and his percentage width inside a table in chrome.

I have this HTML:

```
<table><tr>
    <td><input type='date'/></td>
    <td><input type='text'/></td>
<tr></table>
```

And this CSS:

```
table {
  width: 200px;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

it makes this result:

[image]

As you can see both widths are different (date input is 150px and text input is 45px).

I tried changing date input width to 50%:

```
input[type=date] {
  width: 50%;
}
```

The result again is unexpected:

[image]

date input is now 80px and `<td>` keeps being 150px.

Ok, lets try reducing `<td>` width then... I tried 50%, 25% and even 10% with no results

```
td:first-child{
  width: 10%;
}
```

[image]

I can set the date input width using exact pixels (example: 50px), but, is not what I want, because table width can go wider, So, I need a way to make it work with percentage, just like text input works.

Thank you in advance!

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
  <td><input type='date'/></td>
  <td><input type='text'/></td>
<tr></table>
```

Comment: So where's the question ?

Comment: ...and don't use tables for layout?

Comment: Try usng `table-layout:fixed` on the `table`.

Comment: Q: How to make it work with percentage, just like text input works?

Comment: Paulie_D, seems like that works! :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try usng `table-layout:fixed` on the `table`

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.wider {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='date' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <tr>
</table>

<table class="wider">
  <tr>
    <td><input type='date' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the:

```
 input {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8m1s9pu9/

Comment: Thank you, doing that makes table width 328px, table width can change, so I need them as percentage :(